# Mask or hide url from a music stream

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to mask the external URLs of some songs and the user can reproduce them from the browser. Being URL's outside the server I can not put them (I think that it is) as friendly URL

Now there is something like this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://X.X.X.X/music/12345pd?so=/stream" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

And if the user looked the source code in the browser, he should not see the URL, or in any case, he would have to see something like this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://myweb/Rock" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

I do not care if the solution is jquery, javascript ... or make another method of reproduction.

Comment: Totally pointless. Once you modify them to be valid user can inspect source in browser dev tools network. Anything sent to browser is easily accessible

Comment: The idea is to change it in the server, and that it arrives differently in the browser. Something similar to 301

Comment: Then that is a server side task, not client side

Comment: Yes charlietfl, but I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of those who has upvoted @charlietfl's comment, however you may do something like below:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string value = rnd.Next(int.MaxValue).ToString()
Session[trackid] = value;

<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://myweb/Play/trackid=@Session[trackid]&value=@value" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Then in Play Page:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Play([FromUri] string trackid, [FromUri] string value)
{   
    if(Session[trackid] == value)
   {
    byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(trackid + ".ogg");   
     Random rnd = new Random();
     Session[trackid] = rnd.Next(int.MaxValue).ToString();       
    return File(b, "audio/ogg");
   }
  return Content("");
}
```

This will make your link to work only once when the page loads and if user copies the link, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks por your answer.